# Ajax thinks there is still data to be sent but there isn't?

Tags: javascript, ajax

When I reach the end of the data, I still get an alert saying there is still data but nothing else sends.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var limit = 5;
    var start = 0;
    var action = 'inactive';
    function load_quote_data(limit, start)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{limit:limit, start:start},
            cache:false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('#load_quotes').append(data);
                if(!data){
                    alert('empty');
                    /*$('#load_data_message').html("<button type='button' class='btn-info'> No Data Found </button>");*/
                    action = 'active';
                    
                }
                else 
                {
                    alert('loading');
                    /*$('#load_data_message').html("<button type='button' class='btn-info'> Please Wait... </button>");*/
                    action = 'inactive';
                }
            }
        })
    }
    
    if (action == 'inactive')
    {
        action = 'active';
        load_quote_data(limit, start);
    }
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#load_quotes").height() && action == 'inactive')
        {
            action = 'active';
            start = start + limit;
            setTimeout(function() {
                load_quote_data(limit, start);
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

I tried using `(data == "" || data == null)`, `(data.length == 0)`, and I even tried switching them when I used `if(data)`, but nothing seems to work. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: You're only calling the function once. If you want to send another Ajax request after one has succeeded, you can call the function again inside the `success` callback.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? And wouldn't that like resend the same data twice?

Comment: There is no enough information to solve your problem: maybe fetch.php is never empty, or maybe you are receiving an error as response (to track errors add `error: function(err) {...}` after your success callback).

Comment: You call the function the same way as you already have done: `load_quote_data(limit, start);`. To avoid sending the same data you should pass different values other than `limit` and `start` (or change those values before you call the function)

Comment: @DanieleAlessandra thanks but I don't get an error message when I console log it

Comment: @RobinZigmond I tried this but the data keeps resending until it eventually freezes up

Comment: If it is saying it is not empty, it probably is not empty `console.log(escape(data));`

Comment: You're right, it wasn't empty. I have scripts inside my `fetch.php`